# How can I keep a HTTP connection alive if I am making the first request outside of the main fetch function in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, fetch-api, keep-alive, undici

I have the following fetch function which I use with the undici fetch library:

```
async function call() {
        return await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/', {
            dispatcher: new Agent({
                keepAliveTimeout: 100000000,
                keepAliveMaxTimeout: 100000000
              }),
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
    
            body: JSON.stringify({
                'a': 2,
                'b': '0x',
                'data': `${Data}`,
                'limit': 100,
                'loops': 1,
                'value': '0'
                
            })
            
            
        }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
            //console.log(responseData);
            return responseData;
        })
        .catch(error => console.warn(error));
        
        
    };
```

I am running a highly time sensitive application and need to make a post request with sub 1ms latency . The api server is running on localhost .

After establishing there was a bottleneck due to the fact that each time I called the function it would establish a new TCP / HTTP connection, I started looking into keepalive and added the dispatcher arguments which seem to do the trick with undici fetch .

Since the first request is the one that opens the TCP connection, I created a separate function which is basically a mirror of the call function in order to establish the tcp connection before call() is called .

However, I am unable to keep the connection alive this way, and only when the txsend function gets called multiple times (after the first time) it seems to eliminate the overhead cost of establishing a new TCP connection .

How can I create a new TCP / HTTP connection before my call() function is used in order to avoid establishing a new one when I call my main function ?

Comment: Why don't you use websockets?

Comment: Fair point and that was my initial idea but I was told the difference would be negligible if the http server was running FastHttp (I am using GoFiber FastHTTP Golang API server) and honestly never thought it would have such a high overhead cost .

The other reason is that I need to get a reply back from the API, I know there are workarounds for this using websockets as well but the API is already developed as HTTP so if possible I would rather not rewrite all of it and use KeepAlive instead .

Comment: Try to use something like [gRPC](https://grpc.io/). You get network over http2 protocol, bi-directional and structured communication. From our experience, it's very efficient and quick.

Comment: It's definitely more efficient to send a single webSocket packet (on an already established webSocket connection) than it is to send an http request, even if you're trying to reuse an existing http connection.

Comment: @EvgeniDikerman thanks for the recommendation will check that for other upcoming projects, but right now would prefer to deal with this specific issue and avoid having to rewrite all the code again. Keepalive should do the trick for sub 1ms requests on a localhost environment once the connection is already established .

Comment: Im not familiar with undici lib, but verify that you server receive `Connection: keep-alive` and `Keep-Alive: timeout=XXX, max=XXX` headers and behave correctly.

Comment: You could use the WebRTC API or a product like [Agora](https://www.agora.io/en/) to help with realtime connections. Also, Undici docs suggest using FastifyJS with `undici.dispatcher.stream()` for "fast-as-possible requests from one server to another".

Comment: Would you not need to create a (single) global dispatcher and pass it in to the fetch function (as opposed to creating a new one each time you invoke `call`)?